# Скрипт работает но завершается с ошибкой Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Как это исправить? При том что скрипт работает и отправляет данные в БД

Ошибка полностью

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean in W:\domains\localhost\DB.php:26 Stack trace: #0 W:\domains\localhost\handler.php(39): DB->query('INSERT INTO sho...') #1 {main} thrown in W:\domains\localhost\DB.php on line 26
```

Handler.php

```
<?php

require_once 'DB.php';


$grade_ch = check_input($_POST["grade"], "Введите класс!");
$sho_name_ch = check_input($_POST["sho_name"], "Введите имя!");
$radio_ch = check_input($_POST["y_n"], "Да или нет?");
$b_day_ch = check_input($_POST["b_day"], "Ввведите дату");

//Если при заполнении формы были допущены ошибки сработает следующий код:
function check_input($data, $problem = "")
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0) {
        show_error($problem);
    }
    return $data;
}

function show_error($myError)
{
    ?>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>Пожалуйста исправьте следующую ошибку:</p>
    <?php echo $myError; ?>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    exit();
}

$grade = $_POST["grade"];
$sho_name = $_POST["sho_name"];
$y_n = $_POST["y_n"];
$b_day = $_POST["b_day"];

$result = DB::getInstance()->query("INSERT INTO sholar (grade, sho_name, y_n, b_day) VALUES ('$grade', '$sho_name', '$y_n', '$b_day')");


if ($result == true) {
    echo "Информация занесена в базу данных";
} else {
    echo "Информация не занесена в базу данных";
}


// }
```

DB.php

```
<?php
class DB {
    private $_mysqli,
            $_query,
            $_results = array(),
            $_count = 0;

    public static $instance;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
            self::$instance = new DB();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'test');
        if ($this->_musqli->connect_error) {
            die($this->_mysqli->connect_error);
        }
    }

    public function query($sql) {
        if ($this->_query = $this->_mysqli->query($sql)) {
              while ($row = $this->_query->fetch_object()) {
                $this->_results[] = $row;
              }
              $this->_count = $this->_query->num_rows;
        }
        return $this;
    }



    public function results() {
        return $this->_results;
    }

    public function count() {
        return $this->_count;
    }
}
```

строка 26 класса db

```
while ($row = $this->_query->fetch_object()) {
```

Answer (score 1):

[mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.query.php) возвращает `false`, в случае неудачного запроса в БД. Отсюда и ошибка. Попробуйте сделать проверку в методе query

```
public function query($sql)
{
    $this->_query = $this->_mysqli->query($sql);
    if (!$this->_query) {
        throw new \Exception('something is wrong with a query' . $this->_mysqli->error);
    }

    while ($row = $this->_query->fetch_object()) {
        $this->_results[] = $row;
    }
    $this->_count = $this->_query->num_rows;

    return $this;
}
```